# How to remove a part of an ellipse?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The first image is the image I came up with, but I want it to look like the 2nd image. I dont know how to remove the top part of the ellipse.

Here's the code I have for the first image:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.4444444444444444cm,y=0.47619047619047616cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.4444444444444444cm,y=0.47619047619047616cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-9.0,
xmax=9.0,
ymin=-1.5,
ymax=9.0,
xtick={-8.0,-6.0,...,8.0},
ytick={-0.0,2.0,...,8.0},]
\clip(-9.,-1.5) rectangle (9.,9.);
\fill[line width=0.8pt,fill=black,fill opacity=0.4000000059604645] (-5.199690989913828,1.960131022173449) -- (-5.2,0.) -- (5.2,0.) -- (5.200132906169648,1.777484743917159) -- (5.200146577573657,1.9603258574417475) -- (4.894074114340027,1.8358240186682537) -- (4.383736317446814,1.6540003026338357) -- (3.856667569065835,1.4954987779387272) -- (3.3057923380648537,1.3574824290886491) -- (2.3783912799393305,1.1808621745376695) -- (1.255093854183623,1.0495335902835947) -- (0.3914055491874345,1.0047903153881497) -- (-0.3005995430058771,1.0028247500658463) -- (-1.3050347730614216,1.0535812360729975) -- (-2.5429095834588207,1.2074543229397592) -- (-3.5252600258333797,1.4092987540641437) -- (-4.4555061691745905,1.6777844449657104) -- cycle;
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,5.)},line width=1.2pt] (0.,5.) ellipse (3.5555555555555554cm and 1.9047619047619047cm);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt] (-6.093216873727635,7.591944643010381)-- (6.027793299628012,7.629910071511935);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (-5.199690989913828,1.960131022173449)-- (-5.2,0.);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (5.2,0.)-- (5.200146577573657,1.9603258574417475);
\draw (-1.0689909579527075,-0.05725192695312553) node[anchor=north west] {$\textbf{O}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can draw an arc. But you'd need to know one of the starting coordinates and the relevant angles. You can also clip it. Note that clipping in most cases requires scoping.

Comment: You're using the `axis` environment but not the `\addplot` command of the PGFPlots package. Are you using PGFPlots only for the axes? It's a bit overkill …

Answer (score 5):

Polar coordinates are your friend here.

The first path draws the gray area by drawing only the lower part of the ellipse (from angle −135° to angle −45°) and a box below that.

The second part draws the whole ellipse segment [from angle 30° to (−180−30)°] but we will save the start and end point in coordinate so that the third path can use them to draw the dashed line between them.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, x radius=3, y radius=2, >=Stealth, line cap=round]
\draw[fill=lightgray, near start]
  (-135:3 and 2)
  arc[start angle=-135, end angle=-45]
  -- ++(down:1)
  -| coordinate (O)
     node[below left] {$O$} cycle;
\draw (30:3 and 2) coordinate (start)
  arc[start angle=30, endangle=-180-30] coordinate (end);
\draw[dashed] (start) -- (end);

\path[->] ([shift=(down: .5)]O) edge node[at end, right] {$y$} ++(   up:5)
          ([shift=(left:4)  ]O) edge node[at end, below] {$x$} ++(right:8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @hi, the curve drawn is not the same ellipse as the one proposed?

Comment: @rpapa Well, angles and radii can be adjusted. I've updated my answer anyway. Maybe 1.5 for the *x* radius is also better.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

[image]

Code (ATTENTION: the order of different lines is very important!):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]  
        \draw[fill=gray] (-1.2,0) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (-2.2,-.5) rectangle (2.2,1.5);
            \filldraw[fill=white,draw=blue,line width=2pt,opacity=1] (0,1) ellipse(1.6 and .8);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (2.2,0) node[right] {$x$};   % x-axis
        \draw[-latex] (0,-.5) -- (0,2.2) node[above] {$y$};   % y-axis
        \node at (-.2,-.2) () {$O$}
        \draw[dashed] (-1.2,1.5)--(1.2,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a test with my new tkz-elements package. I've generalised the situation. Here the ellipse is defined by its two foci and the vertex point (east of the ellipse) but it can be defined in two other ways. The ends of the dotted segment are determined using the `point` method, which gives a point on the ellipse by varying an angle between 0 and 2ft.

Then the object ellipse have attributs, useful for drawing it with TikZ or tkz-euclide; it's about Rx, Ry and slope

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
   
\begin{tkzelements}
   z.F1     = point: new (-1 , 4)
   z.F2     = point: new (3 , 0)
   L.F1F2   = line : new (z.F1,z.F2)
   z.V      = L.F1F2: point (1.2)
   E        = ellipse: foci (z.F1,z.F2,z.V)
   z.a      = E : point (math.pi/4)
   z.b      = E : point (3*math.pi/4)
   L.ab     = line : new (z.b,z.a)
   z.c      = L.ab : equilateral ().pc
   z.C      = E.center
   a        = E.Rx
   b        = E.Ry
   slope    = math.deg(E.slope)
  set_lua_to_tex  {'a','b','slope'}
\end{tkzelements}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,ymin=-3,xmax=7,ymax=7]
\tkzClip
\begin{scope}
   \tkzClipCircle[out](c,a)
   \tkzDrawEllipse[blue](C,\a,\b,\slope)
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed](a,b)
   \tkzDrawPoints(C,V,F1,F2,a,b)
   \tkzLabelPoints(C,V,F1,F2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]